# Problem with Google Oauth callback url parameters

Tags: laravel-5, google-oauth

We have implemented oauth authentication with google in our app with Laravel 5.5.

Today connecting one client we got a problem with the response.

With this uri, the request is empty:

`https://example.com/datasources/googleauthcallback?state=SOMESTATE&code=OURGREATCODE&scope=email%20profile%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly`

dd($request) prints []...

But the same URL without the scope, works...

`https://example.com/datasources/googleauthcallback?state=SOMESTATE&code=OURGREATCODE`

dd($request) prints state = SOMESTATE and code = OURGREATCODE

In our machines the first URL works correctly, but not the second one.

We think is something about the server configuration, what could be?
We use Apache + PHP 7.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem on my server, the solution was in the apache vhost configuration file, add this option:

```
AllowEncodedSlashes On
```

Our server was updated and we lost this configuration.

Comment: Thanks, I will check this